# Duplicate Error when inserting unique non duplicate values T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, unique-index

Here is my other mistake I can't fight:

I am trying to add (INSERT INTO sql statement) a unique records from the WHID field 
(ClientEpisode table) into WHID field (EHREpisode table):

```
      INSERT INTO 
                  [WH].[Fact].EHREpisode ([WHID])
         SELECT
               [HP].[bhcms5].ClientEpisode.WHID
         FROM
             [HP].[bhcms5].ClientEpisode
```

Both of the WHID fields are unique (non duplicated) in both tables, and between each others, but I keep having an error:

[image]

Plz, see the error message, in bigger letters:

"**Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'Fact.EHREpisode' with unique index 'IX_EHREpisode'. The duplicate key value is (NULL, NULL>).
The statement has been terminated.**"

Below are my tables structures:

EHREpisode:
[image]

ClientEpisode:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is very clear: There is a unique index called `IX_EHREpisode` with such columns that your query tries to insert the value (null,null) two times.

You have provided us a set of SSMS GUI pictures that are not really relevant to this. Instead, the way to use the GUI would be:

- Go to the "Object explorer" at the left of SSMS
- Find the table "EHREpisode" you are interested in
- Open "Indexes". You should find `IX_EHREpisode` here. Open it.
- Inside you will see the columns included in this index. There will be a couple of these that would both take NULL value if your query executed

Thus, you will either have to modify the index, or re-think your query.

Answer (score 3):

The error message seems to be saying something about `NULL` values being the culprit (your screen capture is hard to read).  So, you may try excluding `NULL` values from being inserted:

```
INSERT INTO [WH].[Fact].EHREpisode ([WHID])
SELECT [HP].[bhcms5].ClientEpisode.WHID
FROM [HP].[bhcms5].ClientEpisode
WHERE [HP].[bhcms5].ClientEpisode.WHID IS NOT NULL;
```

As an alternative, consider using an index on `WHID` which ignores `NULL` values:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_col1
ON [HP].[bhcms5].ClientEpisode (WHID)
WHERE WHID IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, none of the above helped :(

It created unique nonclustered index (from your 2nd advice), but I am still getting the same mistake: 

"Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'Fact.EHREpisode' with unique index 'IX_EHREpisode'. The duplicate key value is (<NULL>, <NULL>).
The statement has been terminated."

I will update my original post with the error message (bigger font)

Comment: Please tell us what this index is?  Show the definition if possible.